# ggplot multiple pie chart on one df not showing right ratio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create multiple pie chart for a dataframe

```
    
|header| value1 |value2|Functionality |
|:-----|:-------|:-----|:-------------|
|k1    |69918   |116345|Non Functional|
|k2    |12595   |51755 |Non Functional|
|k3    |10482   |14973 |Non Functional|
|k4    |53590   |115612|Non Functional|
|k5    |10531   |18635 |Non Functional|
|k6    |10406   |16838 |Non Functional|
|k7    |14159   |24417 |Non Functional|
|k8    |11913   |18754 |Non Functional|
|k9    |8844    |15266 |Non Functional|
|k1    |4101077 |3739815   |Functional|
|k2    |723353  |1440359   |Functional|
|k3    |617290  |377484    |Functional|
|k4    |1584932 |1598903   |Functional|
|k5    |811679  |776848    |Functional|
|k6    |692557  |633247    |Functional|
|k7    |903137  |878248    |Functional|
|k8    |742021  |695467    |Functional|
|k9    |380319  |363830    |Functional|
```

I did the following following this guide: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-multiple-pie-charts-using-ggplot2-in-r/

```
df$Germline <- factor(df$header)
df$Functionality <- factor(df$Functionality)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=" ", y=value1, group=Functionality, colour=Functionality, fill=Functionality)) +
         geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
         coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
         facet_grid(.~ header) +theme_void()
```

But my results I am getting
[image]

The value seems to be add up for all existing value instead of each individual header, what did I do wrong here and how do I fix it?

Also, additional question is ggplotly seems won't work on multiple pie chart, is that the case, want to show percentage of each.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might need to get the relative percent for each header group.
Try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
tibble(header = c("k1", "k2", "k3", "k4", "k5", "k6", "k7", "k8", "k9", "k1", "k2", "k3", "k4", "k5", "k6", "k7", "k8", "k9"), 
       value1 = c(69918L, 12595L, 10482L, 53590L, 10531L, 10406L, 14159L, 11913L, 8844L, 4101077L, 723353L, 617290L, 1584932L, 811679L, 692557L, 903137L, 742021L, 380319L), 
       value2 = c(116345L, 51755L, 14973L, 115612L, 18635L, 16838L, 24417L, 18754L, 15266L, 3739815L, 1440359L, 377484L, 1598903L, 776848L, 633247L, 878248L, 695467L, 363830L), 
       functionality = c("Non Functional", "Non Functional", "Non Functional", "Non Functional", "Non Functional", "Non Functional", "Non Functional", "Non Functional", "Non Functional", "Functional", "Functional", "Functional", "Functional", "Functional", "Functional", "Functional", "Functional", "Functional"))

df %>% 
  group_by(header) %>%
  mutate(pct_value = value1/sum(value1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= " ", y = pct_value, group = functionality, colour = functionality, fill = functionality)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
  facet_wrap(~header, nrow = 3) + 
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked, took me a while to update all package for ggplot and group_by to work with %>%, One question, is it possible to make it like 5 on first row and 4 on second row, or 3 x 3  so the plot looks bigger?

Comment: Sure! See the edits to `facet_wrap()` which now has `nrow = 3`.